# Difference between RowID and REF of an Object Table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I would like to know the difference between ROWID and the REF (which gives the OID) of an object Table?

like, we query:

```
select rowid from emp;
```

and

```
select ref(e) from XX_OBJ_TABLE e;

// here XX_OBJ_TABLE is the object table of some XX_OBJ Object Type.
```

and

```
select rowid from XX_OBJ_TABLE;
```

please tell me the difference.

Much Appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Rowid is physical row address. REF implies hidden foreign key on hidden column which identifies uniquely object record.

As I remember from the first Tom Kyte book, this column is not indexed so it might cause locking issue when you delete from master table.